# Property does not exist on type CombinedVueInstance

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

My typescript compiler won’t add returned `data` types to the `CombinedVueInstance`. My component:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return { title: '' };
  },
  head() {
    return { title: this.title };
  },
});
```

On compile (and in Vetur) I get the error `Property 'title' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, unknown, unknown, unknown, Readonly<Record<never, any>>>'.`, same if I try to use `this.title` in  a computed property or somewhere else.

I’m using Nuxt (v2.15.7) configured with @nuxt/typescript-build and @nuxt/types at the appropriate places.

Comment: Did you find the root cause ?